# disable textbox in gridview on specific condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have textbox column in my gridview. I want to disable my textbox in certain condition i.e 
when value entered in texbox is 2000 then "2000/500= 4" textbox will be disable on other rows it should be multiple of certain value .

I don't know which event should fire in `gridview` or use `javascript` for handling the `textboxchange event`.

Here is my grid view code .aspx

```
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Installment No.">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblInstl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("InstallmentNo") %>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LbldueDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DueDate") %>' Font-Bold="True" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deposit Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Datedeposit") %>'  Enabled='<%# (string) Eval("Datedeposit") == "" %>'  ID="TxtdepositDate" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amount") %>' Enabled='<%# (string) Eval("Amount") == "" %>' Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hdn" Value='<%#Eval("InstallmentAmount") %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

if the amount entered by the user in the Textamount is greater than 500 then i want to disable next 3 textbox of my gridview row.

Comment: Could you show some code

Comment: i have only written my gridview databinding code..

Comment: Its hard to understand the content of your question. Perhaps post some pics/screenshots describing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This comes in two parts.

**PART 1** *At run-time*

You should look at the `RowDataBound` event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.100).aspx

So the declaration of the GridView is

```
<asp:GridView id="grd" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound">
```

Then in the code-behind you can check a condition off of `e`, like in the example above:

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Display the company name in italics.
      if(int.Parse(((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[2].FindCOntrol("TxtdepositDate")).Text) > 500)
      {
         (((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[2].FindCOntrol("TxtAmount")).Enabled = false;
      }     
    }    
}
```

**PART 2** *Client Side*

Then I'd look to use jQuery to disable the textbox when text is entered client side:

First, add a class to the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Datedeposit") %>'  Enabled='<%# (string) Eval("Datedeposit") == "" %>'  ID="TxtdepositDate" Width="200px" CssClass="watchedAmt"></asp:TextBox>
```

And to the other textbox:

' Enabled='<%# (string) Eval("Amount") == "" %>' Width="200px" CssClass="targetTxt">

Then, jQuery can keep an eye on those textboxes easier:

```
$(".watchedAmt").change(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 500) {
        $(this).parent().next().child(".targetTxt").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next().child(".targetTxt").removeAttr("disabled");
    };
});
```

The targeting in the jQuery may be a bit off, as you need to do it based on your grid layout, but it should get you close.

Give it a go.

Comment: i have one textbox column and one date column. when user enters the value in textbox then on the basis of i have to disable other gridview textbox column .

Comment: You're going to have to post your markup to make this easier... And do you want this to happen client side? So not a condition of the data in the grid, but the user's input?

Comment: depending upon the user input on textbox in gridview i want to disable my other gridview rows.

Comment: OK, you're going to have to post up your markup for anyone to help. And it'll need to be client side I guess.